# Bibliography insertion prevents compilation

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am trying to print a bibliography, following the example of the ShareLaTeX site.  I have a `bibliography.bib` file with the following contents:

```
@Article{sasai,
     author =       "Yoshiki Sasai",
     title =        "{Cytosystems dynamics in self-organization of tissue architecture}",
     journal =      "Nature",
     volume =       "493",
     number =       "7432",
     pages =        "318--326",
     year =         "2013/01/17",
     publisher =    "Nature Publishing Group",
     ISBN =         "0028-0836",
     URL =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature11859",
     type =         "10.1038/nature11859",
}
```

And I have a main file with:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

As far as the information I have gleaned so far is concerned, this ought to produce a bibliography entry.  What is going wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you run BibTeX? I'm no expert with ShareLaTeX, but this operation is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the following MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{sasai,
     author =       "Yoshiki Sasai",
     title =        "{Cytosystems dynamics in self-organization of tissue architecture}",
     journal =      "Nature",
     volume =       "493",
     number =       "7432",
     pages =        "318--326",
     year =         "2013/01/17",
     publisher =    "Nature Publishing Group",
     ISBN =         "0028-0836",
     URL =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature11859",
     type =         "10.1038/nature11859",
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain} % <===========================================
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

In your code the definition of the bibliography style is missing.  I added it (see line with marking `% <==============`

Result:

[image]